# Why does the value of x is not updating ? is there anything wrong with the code ? i'm new to javascript

Tags: javascript, module, node-modules, es6-modules, revealing-module-pattern

```js
var ModuelPattern=(function () {
    var x="A"
    var change=function(){
        if(x==="A"){
            x="B"
        }
        else{
            x="A"
        }
    }
    return{
        x:x,
        f:change
    }
  })();
  
  ModuelPattern.f()
  console.log(ModuelPattern.x)
```

I cannot figure out an way to update x inside IIFE using revealing-module pattern and access outside the
Scope

Answer (score 0):

You can make `x` a *getter* function in the returned object:

```
var ModuelPattern=(function () {
    var x="A"
    var change=function(){
        if(x==="A"){
            x="B"
        }
        else{
            x="A"
        }
    }
    return{
        get x() { return x; },
        set x(_) {},
        f:change
    }
  })();
  
  ModuelPattern.f()
  console.log(ModuelPattern.x)
```

That allows the returned object to access the local variable in the closure formed from calling the original factory function. I added a dummy setter function as an illustration.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword to access object's own properties.

```js
var ModuelPattern=(function () {
    this.x = "A"
    this.change=function() {
        if(this.x==="A"){
            this.x = "B"
        }
        else{
            this.x = "A"
        }
    }
    return {
        x: this.x,
        f: this.change
    }
})();

console.log(ModuelPattern.x)
ModuelPattern.f()
console.log(ModuelPattern.x)
```

Comment: This changes the semantics of the code in the OP. The variable `x` in the constructor (from the OP) is not directly visible via the property name "x" on the object; in your answer, it is.